# MGE UPS Switched PDU

Tags: hardware, electrical-power, ups, power-supply-unit

I have an old MGE Switched PDU unit.
The one described in this manual: http://www.manualslib.com/manual/102923/Mge-Ups-Systems-Switched-Pdu.html

I didn't use it in years and couldn't remember the admin password of the unit.

I reset it to factory defaults following the procedure described in the manual and did try with the default username/password: admn/admn from the manual but with no luck.

I think the "reset to factory defaults" procedure worked ok but I think I have an old firmware that has a different default password than the admn/admn given in the manuals.

Does anyone with experience with older devices from MGE (www.mgeups.com) knows of some different username/password they used to set as defaults before the admn/admn pair they use now?

Or some other ideas on default username/passwords I could try?

Comment: reset it again ? my guess is that the reset didnt worked.

Comment: I tried it several times. Still not possible to log in into it with the default login.

Comment: The pic looks a bit like the APC units. you could try apc/apc or mge/mge or snmp/1234

Answer (score 2):

To those that may have this same device I found the default username/password.
It is MGEUPS/MGEUPS